# Authorisation design using policies/permission using keycloak or in general

Tags: authorization, keycloak, rbac

I'm quite new to the entire auth design and am still trying to understand how to use keycloak for authentication and authorisation.

Currently from what I understand in order to have authorisation enabled for a client you will need to have it in confidential.

After which I am kind of stuck in terms of how to set which policy for which permission.

I have a few types resources but currently placing them all under a single client for simplicity sake.

For my use case I have a workspace for users. So each workspace can have multiple users with different roles of  owner,editor,viewer. And within the workspace there are artifacts. So it is some what like designing an authorisation for Google drive.

Would like some advice on how best to design it.

One way I have thought of is using groups and each workspace is a group. Using it to assign users to each group as a way to use the group policy for permission.

The other is really by creating multiple policy and permission for each artifact/resource and adding user to each policy for each workspace.

Would like any advice on authorisation design or even where to begin reading.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have come to these conclusion.

Yes these can be done by keycloak though most likely shouldn't be done in keycloak itself for its design.

Keycloak itself will most likely be more suitable in terms of authenticating/authorising on services or infra level. So this use case of having user be able to access workspaces or artifacts will be better done in application level having a separated service to handle the permission itself.

That being said if it really needs to be done in keycloak the design that I thought of that is not so scalable is as follow.

Create a policy/user and each workspace/artifact as a single resource. Depending on how many types of access/fine grain control is needed for each type of resource create the scope for each (e.g workspace:view, workspace:edit...). Then create a permission for each resource&scope. This allows fine grain access of basically assigning user to permission of each resource through the user policy.

But of course this design has its flaws of the need of too many policies, permissions and resources so it is better to have keycloak just handle the authentication part and authorisation is just giving users the role to be able to access a service and through the service check if the user is authorised for a certain action.